# Bootstrap: re-arrange panels like a puzzle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on an app and can't get bootstrap to adapt like jquery_ui would do it (for example).
I'd like the different blocks (which are columns and that's the main problem) to re-arrange so that there wouldn't be any huge white space between them. That's of course not the way bootstrap operates but I need that anyway for 1 specific layout.

Here's a picture of what I would like to achieve:
[image]

Of course, this doesn't work properly. The screenshot you see here is based on col-md-4 elements. Do the math, something is wrong here. Second issue: the panel on the left bottom should be on the right. But since this hack ends up with 16 columns instead of 12 it doesn't make sense anyway.

That's the solution I found:

```
    .row {
     -moz-column-width: 25em;
     -webkit-column-width: 25em;
     -moz-column-gap: 10px;
     -webkit-column-gap:10px; 

    }

    .row > .col-md-4 {
     display: inline-block;
     width:  100%; 
     float:none;
    }
```

I prepared a small jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c19jgvqn/10/

It's actually reacting even worse when you collapse a panel.

Any ideas how to do this in a proper way? I searched but couldn't find any viable solution for this.

Comment: still looking for an answer on this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, months later I finally found the answer. And the right words to describe it:

I was looking for a way to re-arrange bootstrap panels and columns in a masonry style. Not an easy thing to do and it goes against bootstrap's foundation on a grid system.

Still:

Have a look at this link: 
[Tutsplus Bootstrap panels masonry style](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dynamic-grid-with-salvattore-and-bootstrap-in-10-minutes--cms-20410)